# DBF file size is increased after exporting opened shapefile into new shapefile

Tags: geotools, dbf

I have a shapefile (polygon features) which has seven attributes (id, area, etc.,) in the DBF file. After reading the shapefile I am exporting to a new shapefile in which I am adding two attributes (id ,area). But exported DBF file is bigger size than earlier one.

This is my simple feature type schema

```
    builder.setCRS(DefaultGeographicCRS.WGS84); 
    builder.setName(plotIdentifier);

    builder.add(sPolygon, Polygon.class);
    builder.add(plotIdentifier, String.class);
    builder.add(aRea,Float.class);

    final SimpleFeatureType featureType = builder.buildFeatureType();
    return new SimpleFeatureBuilder(featureType);
```

Please help me on this

Code creating polygon:

```
 public boolean addPolygonFeature(List<SimpleFeature> featureList, Point3D[] thePoints,
                                 String polyId, float area)
                                 throws Exception
{
    Polygon aPoly = createPolygon(thePoints);

    if (aPoly == null)
    {
        StringBuffer buf = new StringBuffer();
        buf.append(WError1);
        buf.append(polyId);
        buf.append(WError2);
        String error = buf.toString();

        int opt = GUIBase.showConfirmDialog(error, "Confirm", GUI_YN);
        return (opt == GUIBase.GUI_YES);
    }

    SimpleFeature feature = featureBuilder.buildFeature(null);
    feature.setAttribute(plotIdentifier, polyId.trim());
    feature.setAttribute(sPolygon, aPoly);
    feature.setAttribute(aRea, area);
    featureList.add(feature);
    return true;
}

public Polygon createPolygon(Point3D[] thePoints)
{
    int count = (thePoints == null) ? 0 : thePoints.length;
    if (count < 1) return null;

    // Store Coordinates of polygon as a LINESTRING.
    StringBuffer buffer = new StringBuffer();
    buffer.append("POLYGON((");

    for (int i=0; i<count; i++)
    {
        buffer.append(thePoints[i].x);
        buffer.append(SPACE);
        buffer.append(thePoints[i].y);
        buffer.append(COMMA);
    }

    String lineString = buffer.toString();
    lineString = lineString.substring(0, lineString.length()-1) + "))";
    if (DEBUG) System.out.println(lineString);

    try
    {
        // Creating the Geometry (Polygon)
        return (Polygon) wktReader.read(lineString); 
    }
    catch (Exception excep) { }

    return null;
}

public void writeShape(File theFile, List<SimpleFeature> featureList) throws Exception
{ 
    ShapefileDataStoreFactory dSFactory = new ShapefileDataStoreFactory();

    Map params = new HashMap();
    params.put("url", theFile.toURI().toURL());
    params.put("create spatial index", Boolean.TRUE);

    ShapefileDataStore newDataStore =
                 (ShapefileDataStore) dSFactory.createNewDataStore(params);

    newDataStore.createSchema(featureBuilder.getFeatureType());
    newDataStore.forceSchemaCRS(DefaultGeographicCRS.WGS84);

    String typeName = newDataStore.getTypeNames()[0];
    SimpleFeatureSource featureSource =
                                   newDataStore.getFeatureSource(typeName);
    if (featureSource instanceof SimpleFeatureStore) 
    {
        SimpleFeatureStore featureStore = (SimpleFeatureStore)featureSource;
        SimpleFeatureCollection collection =
                  new ListFeatureCollection(featureBuilder.getFeatureType(),
                                            featureList);
        Transaction transaction = new DefaultTransaction("create");
        featureStore.setTransaction(transaction);
        try
        {
            featureStore.addFeatures(collection);
            transaction.commit();
        }
        catch (Exception exp)
        {
            exp.printStackTrace();
            transaction.rollback();
        } 
        finally
        {
            transaction.close();
        }
    }
}
```

And shapefile link as given below:

https://docs.google.com/file/d/0B5Vh2tWJlQW_RURQaFBwaDJ6ckk/edit?usp=sharing

```
Read shapefile: 1.shp
Written shapefile: 2.shp
```

Comment: I think we need more code to help. Also what does the dbf file look like if you open it with a spreadsheet?

Comment: if i open the dbf file it has 2 attributes and values and the values are correct ones.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you write out your second shapefile you haven't specified the sizes of the columns so they have defaulted to the largest possible size.

You need to add something (like):

```
builder.setCRS(DefaultGeographicCRS.WGS84); 
builder.setName(plotIdentifier);

builder.add(sPolygon, Polygon.class);
//restrict length of string to 10 chars
builder.length(10);
builder.add(plotIdentifier, String.class);
builder.add(aRea,Float.class);
```